# Поиск ближайшего значения в массиве, к заданому

Tags: массивы, поиск, числа

Есть код, он сортирует массив, как найти ближайшее число в массиве к заданому(point)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russia");
    int point, a;

    cout << "Enter point" << endl;
    cin >> point;

    const int x = 5;
    int xpoint[x];
    cout << "Enter points that are located along the X axis" << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        cout << "[ " << i << " ] = ";
        cin >> xpoint[i];

    }
    cout << "Source array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        cout << xpoint[i] << " "; // Вывод i-го элемента
    }
    cout << endl;

        /* Отсортируем массив по убыванию */
        for (int i = 1; i < x; ++i)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < x - i; r++)
            {
                if (xpoint[r] > xpoint[r + 1])
                {
                    // Обмен местами
                    int temp = xpoint[r];
                    xpoint[r] = xpoint[r + 1];
                    xpoint[r + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        /* Выведем отсортированный массив */
        cout << "sorted array: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        {
            cout << xpoint[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;


       
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "он сортирует массив" - зачем?

Comment: в задании сказали отсортировать масив.

Comment: Есть массив координат точек на оси Х. Найти координату точки, ближайшей к заданной точке.
Сортировка массива методом "Сортировка четное-нечетное"

Comment: Снова переберите массив и внутри цикла  найдите дельта(разность) к нужному числу, их запоминать нужно, у кого наименьшая дельта - тот и ближе.

Comment: А можете дополнить код, а то я что-то не пойму как это написать